# PowerBI Dataset Refresh failed for Web connection

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I have an excel file hosted on sharepoint and I connected to it using my organization account, everything seems to be OK as long as I was refreshing the file on my desktop, the moment I published the PBIX to the power bi workspace and tried to refresh the dataset using OAuth2 authentication method, I got below issue

> ```
> Failed to update data source credentials: SharePoint: Request failed: https://microsoft.sharepoint.com
> ```

What I have tried:

1. I have tried connecting to the excel file on sharepoint use SharePoint Folder connection in Power BI but get the same issue

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you use on-premise SharePoint site? You had to install Microsoft Power BI Gateway and add the Sharepoint source there first. This allows the dataset on PowerBI Service to refresh using the credentials provided by the connected gateway. Below gateway documentation for as a reference. I tested and this has solved my issue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-gateway-onprem-manage-oracle

Add a data source

You can add a data source by either selecting a gateway and click Add data source, or go to Gateway > Add data source.

You can then select the Data Source Type from the list.

Please select Sharepoint List(on-premises) instead of oracle.